# ANTLR4 -> Lexer symbols access from visitors

Tags: java, antlr

Currecntly, I'm implementing a ANTLR4 generated `BaseListener<Void>`.

When I need to check whether a token is one or another, I'm doing things like:

```
@Override
public Void visitTerminal(TerminalNode node) {

    if (";".equals(node.getText()))
        this.prepareQuery();
    else if (",".equals(node.getText()))
        this.prepareQuery();

    return super.visitTerminal(node);
}
```

Is there some way for avoiding these `";"`, `","`?
I'm figure out so, since I've declared this tokens as LEXER rules on my grammar:

```
SCOL : ';';
COMMA : ',';
```

Could I write something like `Lexer.SCOL(...)`, or `Lexer.COMMA.equals(...)`?:

Answer (score 0):

You can get the lexer type from the node via node.getSymbol().getType();

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not quite able to figure out what's `node.getSymbol().getType()` `int` returned value relation there is according `";"` or `","`. What's `int` returned value? How am I able to replace `";".equals(...)` using `node.getSymbol().getType()`

Comment: Oh, I assumed you know that a lexer generates lexer symbols out of the text as this is one of the first things you learn when working with parsers.

Answer (score 0):

Antlr4 generates a `GrammLexer` where contains each Lexer Rule:

So, the replacement would be:

```
@Override
public Void visitTerminal(TerminalNode node) {

    if (GrammLexer.SCOL == node.getSymbol().getType()))
        this.prepareQuery();
    else if (GrammLexer.COMMA == node.getText().getType())
        this.prepareQuery();

    return super.visitTerminal(node);
}
```

Or,

```
@Override
public Void visitTerminal(TerminalNode node) {

    switch (node.getSymbol().getType())
    {
        case GrammarLexer.SCOL:
            break;
        case GrammarLexer.COMMA:
            break;
    }

    return super.visitTerminal(node);
}
```